# Order by relevance, lucene search

Tags: solr, lucene

Search Term:
cristina de oliveira

This is the query:
(name_text:(cristina\ de\ oliveira^200.0 OR cristina\ de\ oliveira*^100.0 OR cristina\ de\ oliveira~^50.0))

This is the result:
MARIA CRISTINA DE OLIVEIRA,
LIA CRISTINA DE OLIVEIRA,
MARISA CRISTINA DE OLIVEIRA,
CRISTINA de OLIVEIRA

Problem:
Since search term is "cristina de olveira", the first result should be "CRISTINA de OLIVEIRA" and not "MARIA CRISTINA DE OLIVEIRA", how can I get exactly search term as the first result

Comment: could you show your schema.xml? so, what is your order, you want full match to be first? or a prefix match to be first?

Comment: I want full match to be the first. I am testing it from solr panel: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/master_Customer/query.

Comment: I tried add sort as "score desc" and I got the previous result

Comment: PS: For all results I got the same score (score": 16742.885), and If i change indexed field value from "CRISTINA de OLIVEIRA" to "CRISTINA OLIVEIRA" I got the expected result

Comment: could you share your schema.xml, it will be difficult to help without it